# How can I automatically wrap the charts_flutter legends?

Tags: flutter, legend

How can I automatically wrap the charts_flutter legends?

## Current state:

[image: now]

## Expected:

[image: aim_1]
[image: aim_2]

I tried,

```
  behaviors: [charts.SeriesLegend(desiredMaxColumns: 2)],
```

But, it has been fixed to two columns.
The number of lines and the legend length are variable.

What should I do?

Comment: I think if you put the desiredMaxColumns to a large number, it will automatically place as many columns  as possible and then wrap the legends to next row. Try if that works.

Comment: Hi dlohani,
Thank you for your comment.
But, it did not work.
I tried "desiredMaxColumns: 5" with 10 items.
But, I could see 6 legends.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't an out-of-the-box solution but you can create your own custom legend builder and layout your legend however you see fit by extending the `charts.LegendContentBuilder` class.

```dart
class CustomLegendBuilder extends charts.LegendContentBuilder{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, LegendState legendState, Legend legend, {bool showMeasures}) {
    /*
      Implement your custom layout logic here. You should take into account how long
      your legend names are and how many legends you have. For starters you
      could put each legend on its own line.
    */

    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 25.0,
      child: Text('MY CUSTOM LEGEND'),
    );
  }
}
```

Now when you construct your chart add the following behavior:

```
...
  behaviors: [
    charts.SeriesLegend.customLayout(
      CustomLegendBuilder(),
      // Other legend properties here
    ),
  ],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for this problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SimpleLineChart.withRandomData(),
    ));
  }
}

class SimpleLineChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;

  SimpleLineChart(this.seriesList);

  factory SimpleLineChart.withRandomData() {
    return SimpleLineChart(
      _createRandomData(),
    );
  }

  /// Create random data.
  static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, num>> _createRandomData() {
    final random = Random();
    List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> s = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < random.nextInt(6); ++i) {
      final data = [
        LinearSales(0, random.nextInt(100)),
        LinearSales(1, random.nextInt(100)),
        LinearSales(2, random.nextInt(100)),
        LinearSales(3, random.nextInt(100)),
      ];
      String title1 = random.nextInt(1000).toString();
      String title2 = random.nextInt(10000).toString();
      s.add(
        charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
          id: 'legend_${title1}_${title2}',
          domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
          measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
          data: data,
        ),
      );
    }
    return s;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return charts.LineChart(
      seriesList,
      behaviors: [charts.SeriesLegend()],
    );
  }
}

/// Sample linear data type.
class LinearSales {
  final int year;
  final int sales;

  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Comment: I think the legend is overflowing the screen, wrapping SimpleLineChart.withRandomData() with a container and see if that helps

Comment: I tried your suggestion.
But it doesn't work. It was the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I tried "desiredMaxColumns: 5" with 10 items.
But, it did not work.
I could see 6 legends.
[image: not work 1]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check the width of the screen and dynamically set the desiredMaxColumns:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // workaround for not-available auto-wrapping of legend
  double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  int maxColumns;

  // change width thresholds according to your needs
  if (width < 600 && width >= 500) {
    maxColumns = 3;
  } else if (width < 500 && width >= 400) {
    maxColumns = 2;
  } else if (width < 400) {
    maxColumns = 1;
  }

  return charts.LineChart(
    seriesList,
    behaviors: [new charts.SeriesLegend(desiredMaxColumns: maxColumns)]
  );
}
```